# Are wellbehaved functions $f: \mathbb R^\infty \to \mathbb {R^\infty}$ sometimes non-measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

A function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$ can only be non measurable if it is not well behaved (in the sense that no function that anyone typically uses in an applied setting will ever be non-measurable).

Is this also the case if $n=\infty$? Or do we have to worry about possible non-measurability there?

Comment: "Anyone typically uses" and "have to worry" are not very well defined. I guess a fairly strong version of your question is whether the Axiom of Choice is necessary to prove existence of non-measurable functions. If so you would never be able to write down a specific example of one.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret, basically my question is whether that still applies if $n=\infty$. If it does, then the fact that I haven’t well defined those terms shouldn’t matter right? Since for any possible reasonable interpretation the answer would be the same.

Comment: in what applied settings do you ever use $\mathbb R^\infty$? And I presume the sigma algebra is the Borel one over the product topology?

Comment: time series, and yes

Comment: Your time series are elements of $\mathbb R^\infty$ "in the [same] sense that no function that anyone typically uses in an applied setting will ever be non-measurable"

Comment: @Gono, what...?

Comment: You claimed that "no function that anyone typically uses in an applied setting will ever be non-measurable". But because you can get a non-measurable function by countable many operations it implies you restrict applications to a finite number of operations. That's ofc true in reality… but then you claim you are using time series and claim they are in $ \mathbb R^\infty$… but as before: applications are restricted to a finite number of operations, so none of your time series in reality will be out of $\mathbb R^\infty$. So your whole question here makes no sense

Comment: @Gono, there are such functions used in theoretical analysis of time series for e.g. consistency proofs. But lets cut off the discussion as I don't think it helps